# To what point is a local SQLite database appropriate in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

In the app I'm working on, I need to store a list of ~1000 recipes — each with a title, image link, and list of instructions. What's the optimal method of storing this data? Parse.com seemed great, but it's discontinuing soon. Is there a simple back-end solution to this? Or would a local SQLite database work well for such a set? I would appreciate any feedback! :)

Comment: 1,000 recipes should be fine for a local SQLite database.

Comment: It makes no sense to compare a local database file to a remote back-end solution. They have completely different uses. You need to clarify your needs a lot more for people to be able to offer appropriate answers. Keep in mind though that questions looking for software recommendations are off topic so be sure your question focuses more on the type of solution and not asking for software recommendations.

Comment: Both are good comments.  Additionally, SQLite and a remote back-end solution are really complementary.  You need to store data locally (SQLite) when the internet is unavailable and later synchronize to a back-end.  Also, using Core Data will help you get better performance than you are likely to develop yourself.

Comment: If in the future you want to use Parse, they've completely open-sourced their backend, so anyone can deploy it on their own servers. Heroku is good for that if you don't want to muck around with setting up your own infrastructure. Here's the link: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server

Answer (score 1):

[Realm](http://realm.io/) is a great local database, you could try using that to store your recipes locally.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is not very dynamic you can keep it locally, SQLite will be the good option for this task.

You have two options

1. You can preload the SQLite db and ship it with the app.
2. You can import data from cloud into local db on app launch.

Use Coredata with with the SQLite persistence store it will make this process very easy (compare to writing sql queries) and also you get concurrency for free from the framework.